# horizontal nav bar items with different number of lines of text

Tags: html

Simple horizontal nav bar for artist portfolio website. I am in the process of changing it from a jpg based site to actually coded, and need to match the nav bar on the following page:

http://cynthia-shaffer.com/animal.html

Notice "Natural Elements", "Animal Photos", and "Henna Tattoos" the text is stacked (2 lines as opposed to 1). I want to replicate this in my ul, but can't seem to figure it out.

my code

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Natural Elements</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Animal Photos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Henna Tattoos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Murals</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Supplementary</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Non-Profit</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

#nav ul li { display: inline; }

#nav ul li a
{
text-decoration: none;
font-family:"Lithos";
font-size:12px;
color:c0944d;
padding: .3em 1em;
}
```

So the question is how to get the word "elements" to appear below "natural", without breaking the integrity of the list.

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use display:block on the A-tag and set a max-width.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't exhibit the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zNVZs/

Answer (score 0):

Apply `display:inline-block` for the `<a>` tags and set the maximum desired width of a menu item using the `max-width` property, this will cause the text to automatically wrap when it exceeds the specified `max-length`

```
#nav ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family:"Lithos";
 font-size:12px;
 color:c0944d;
 padding: .3em 1em;
 display:inline-block;
 max-width:50px;
}
```

*side note:* it's better to apply `display:inline-block` while changing display from `block`, for aligning items horizontally - if you apply `display:inline` like you've applied to the `<li>` , the element will not accept `width` and `height` properties...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/zNVZs/1/)